# Recursive function to check if all digits in an int variable are even

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function to check whether a user input a number which contains all even digits.

What is wrong with my logic? When I tried with "556" result is 1.

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    int *result;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    allEven(num, &result);
    printf("allEven(): %d", result);

}
void allEven(int number, int *result)
{
    if ((number % 10) % 2) // if the last digit is odd
    {
        *result = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *result = 1;
        if ((number / 10) != 0) //not the last digit to evaluate, we call the function again.
        {
            allEven((number / 10), &result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you get a compiler arror at `allEven((number / 10), &result);` second parameter?

Comment: Looks like question 6 of your programming assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write it down this way to compile the code:

```
void allEven(int number, int *result)
{
    if ((number % 10) % 2) // if the last digit is odd
    {
        *result = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *result = 1;
        if ((number / 10) != 0) //not the last digit to evaluate, we call the function again.
        {
            allEven((number / 10), result);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int num;
    int result;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    allEven(num, &result);
    printf("allEven(): %d", result);

}
```

1) "int* result" replace with "int result"

2) "allEven((number/10), &result)" call in main() replace with allEven((number/10), result)

3) you missed a brace in allEven function

Comment: I don't quit get it for the 2nd parameter of allEven. Isn't it asking for an address with (int *result)? So why are we just passing "result", which is a value and not an address when we call allEven?

Comment: when you pass it from main(), you provide it with address of result (via &result). But when you pass it from recursive allEven() call, you have it there already a pointer, so we must use it without "&"

Comment: probably, there are still some errors in logics of the code. Yeah, i think it's useful advice

Answer (score 5):

`allEven((number / 10), &result);` should be replaced with

```
allEven((number / 10), result);
```

Because `allEven` expects second argument of type `int *` and `&result` is `int **`

Also `int *result` should be `int result = 1`

[Working example here](http://ideone.com/dTJDx8)

If you compile with proper warning flags `-W -Wall` for example on gcc (better with `-O2`), you should get proper warnings to correct your code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`int *result;`

With

`int result;`